# Special considerations for using threads in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'd like to start using asynchronous processing in IIS. Edit: I'm talking about using the task parallel library.

For example, on certain page loads I want to log a bunch of crap, send an email, update some tables, etc. But I don't want to make the user wait for me to log all that crap.

So normally what I do is I have a static Queue that I push the log info onto, and then I have a cron job that calls a special page every 10 minutes whose OnLoad flushes out the queue. This works, but it's kind of clunky to setup, especially when you want to log 50 things. I'd rather do this:

```
Task.CreateNew(() => Log(theStuff));
```

However I'm terrified of running tasks in IIS because one slip up and your entire website goes down.

So now I have

```
SafeTask.FireAndForget(() => Log(theStuff));
```

This wraps the delegate in some try/catch and passes it into Task.CreateNew. So if someone changes something that affects something else that generates an exception somewhere else that accidentally gets thrown on the task thread, we get a notification instead of a crashed website. Also, the error notification inside the catch is also inside its own try/catch, and the catch for that also has a try/catch that tries to log in a different way.

Now that I can safely run stuff asynchronously in IIS, what *other* things do I need to worry about before I can start using my SafeTask class?

Comment: Be careful using threads in IIS. IIS already uses threads to process individual requests, and there is a limit to the total number available.

Comment: @joel can I create new threads for this so I don't mess with IIS's limit?

Comment: It's an OS limit, not an IIS limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every request in IIS and .net is processed in one thread by default. This thread comes from a thread pool called the "Application Pool". Existing threads are reused so you can't really use them for thread state unless you clear or set it every time. You define the size of this thread pool using a formula from MSDN in the machine.config or even your web.config.

Now, every async function call is put on a different thread. This includes async web service calls, async page functions, async delegates, etc. This thread comes from the "application pool" thus reducing the number of thread available for IIS to service new requests.

Most likely, your application will work just fine while using async function calls. In case you are worried or you have a lot of async tasks then you may want to create your own thread pool or look at SmartThreadPool on codeplex.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if instead of using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem and equivalents, I use the TaskParallelLibrary, which keeps an internal queue of jobs and set number of threads?

Comment: Threads always come from the same application pool - for IIS hosted apps they come from the application pool in IIS and for self hosted or console/windows apps they come from your own application pool which is created for you by .net by default. This is because thread pools are associated with a process. So, the task parallel library will consume the same threads from your thread pool as your application.

Comment: Thanks, I was misinformed and thought Tasks had their own pool which was limited to just a few threads...

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the page's OnUnload event.  Read about it here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

This event fires after the content is sent to the user (so the user isn't blocked while you do work), and should completely satisfy your requirement without introducing additional threads.

Specific to your question, you should be concerned about thread pool exhaustion only if your load and performance testing suggests you're running up against thread limits.  If you're not then what you propose is certainly reasonable.

Comment: hmm that's interesting, however a lot of this stuff happens deep in App_Code. I suppose I could add all the log objects to the HttpContext Items collection, but is there a global equivalent of page unload that I can use for this?